# In Proposition 1.15 of Folland's Real Analysis, why can we assume I = (a,b]? (on page 34)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I understand why the function $\mu_0$, which we would like to show is a premeasure on the algebra $\mathbb{A}= \{$finite disjoint unions of h-intervals$\}$, is well-defined on this set.

It's also clear that this function takes the empty set to $0$ by it's definition in Folland. To show that $\mu_0$ is premeasure, we then must let a sequence $\{I_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ of disjoint elements of $\mathbb{A}$ be given with $I=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty I_j\in\mathbb{A}$ and show that $\mu_0(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty I_j) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty\mu_0(I_j)$.

In proving the first inequality, I understand that since $I\in\mathbb{A}$, it can be written as the finite disjoint union of h-intervals, but Folland then writes that we can assume $I=(a,b]$. I don't quite understand his explanation of how we are allowed to assume $I=(a,b]$ and I am wondering if someone would be willing to explain this step of the proof to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which inequality?

Comment: Can you make your question self-contained? Not everyone has that book at hand.

Answer (score 6):

Since $\bigcup_1^\infty I_j$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$, it can be written as a finite union of disjoint h-intervals $\Delta_1,\dots,\Delta_n$. Put:

$$A_i=\{j\in\mathbb{N}: I_j\subset \Delta_i\}, \ j=1,\dots,n$$

Note that the $\{A_i\}$ are disjoint, and: $$\bigcup_{j\in A_i} I_j=\Delta_i$$

for each $i$. Since $\mu_0$ is finitely additive:

$$\mu_0\left(\bigcup_1^\infty I_j\right)=\mu_0\left(\bigcup_1^n \Delta_i\right)=\sum_1^n \mu_0(\Delta_i)$$

so if we know that the additivity of $\mu$ holds for the h-intervals $\Delta_i$, we see that it holds for their union.

Comment: So then $\mu_{0}(\Delta_{i})$ is essentially a telescoping sum of the $\mu_{0}(I_{j})$'s? And thank you - this helps clear things up!

Comment: @Searching_for_a_foundation What do you mean by telescoping?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series